# Typing different languages in aspx text box

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Can I use text box to enter different languages based on selected language, example

if I select hindi I shall be able to enter Hindi language in text box
If I select English I shall be able to type English

Can we do this in aspx, c# web application

Answer (score 0):

You can fire an "on text change" event and validate your text.
Keep the last text as a global/static variable, and check the new value. If it is legal, replace the variable with the new text. else, force the textbox text to be the last valid text.
The result is that the user will not be able to type an illegal character (or paste an illegal text).
You may also raise an error, color the text box, etc...

If the user is trying to add a char
Something like:

```
<iframe>
    <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
</iframe>   

private string _currentValue
private const string allowedEnglish = "abcdefg........?.:123456789.....";
private const string allowedSpanish = "abcdefg...?.:123456789....áéíóúüñ¿¡......";

protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isValid = false;
    switch(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
    {
      case "English":
            isValid = Regex.IsMatch(allowedEnglish, TextBox1.Value);
            break;
      case "Spanish":
            isValid = Regex.IsMatch(allowedSpanish, TextBox1.Value);
            break;
    }

    if(isValid)
        _currentValue = TextBox1.Value;
    else
        TextBox1.Value = _currentValue;

}
```

Sure, you may extend it to more languages, use other language validation technics and change customer experience, but this is the idea...